# iOS #define or static const for global strings

Tags: ios

I have a constants.h file that declares a bunch of strings that I use throughout my app. I only have strings and nothing else. Am I supposed to use #define or static NSString const? #define works but I hear its not best practice.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `#define` is a pre-processor macro. That means that it basically goes through your code and replace your macro with what you've defined.

If you use a const, it's going to be a pointer to the string in memory. It's way more efficient than having the same string being allocated wherever/whenever it is used.

To do that, you'll need both .h and .m files. Your .h file will look something like:

```
extern NSString * const YOUR_STRING;
```

And your .m file:

```
NSString * const YOUR_STRING = @"your string";
```

Comment: In simple use cases, the compiler will optimize multiple creations of the same string and create a const anyway. However, with other, non-trivial classes, it is better to have one constant value which is initialized once when the class loads (for example). Consts are also good when wanting to expose a public symbol in public API.

Comment: they will both end up being stored as a constant string in the executable, and in memory...

Comment: What if its a format like @"this is my string with int %i"?

Comment: @user1802143, the `%i` part makes the string a variable, not a constant.

Comment: @leanne.  No.  the %i does not make it a variable.  The %i is just part of the string constant.  You can use it to create another string variable if you actually use it as a format string, but a format string is just a string.

Comment: You're right, @chadbag. The formatted string in the `#define` is still a constant, per se. When used, the `%i` will represent a replaceable integer parameter.